# Bind self referencing data to RadTreeView without unique identifiers

Tags: c#, asp.net, telerik, hierarchy, radtreeview

I have data of the form:

a ⊃ b ⊃ c ⊃ d

a ⊃ b ⊃ c ⊃ d2

a ⊃ b ⊃ c ⊃ d3

a ⊃ b ⊃ c2 ⊃ d

I want to bind it to a telerik RadTreeView control, but the data contains no unique identifiers to establish the hierarchy with.

The only guarantee the data is bound by is that the combination a,b,c,d is unique.

```
    RadTreeView1.DataSource = dataTable; //from SQL
    RadTreeView1.DataTextField = dt.Columns[1].ToString(); // this is fine
    RadTreeView1.DataFieldID = dt.Columns["ID"].ToString(); // this is just the row#
    RadTreeView1.DataFieldParentID = ; // ???
    RadTreeView1.DataBind(); // fails
```

Comment: What exactly is your question?  People are always able to help you more if you clearly state your question and post code you've already tried.  Show more of what you've tried so far instead of "give me codez" and people are always glad to help!

Comment: Really the problem I have is a data one. A block of code might change the data so that then it can be bound to a RadTreeView, but I'm not sure thats the best solution.